# Is perception and understanding a theme in The Moon and Sixpence?

Tags: theme, william-somerset-maugham, the-moon-and-sixpence

In *The Moon and Sixpence*, from the different perspectives of the different characters such as the narrator, Strickland's wife, Ata, Dirk etc show different views on Strickland, and while some of their perceptions of Strickland change throughout the novel, the book does not reveal what Strickland is really like.

Therefore, would perception and understanding be a theme in this book? As the different characters have different views on Strickland owing to different factors. If yes, what is the evidence for this from the text?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature SE. Your question has a close vote, because the guidelines specifically say to avoid asking questions when there is no actual problem to be solved: "I’m curious if other people feel like I do." Using the argument you've made in the question, anybody could say that yes, this is a theme of this novel. So it isn't clear whether you have an actual question, or are merely asking if other people's opinion matches your own. Can you reframe your question to be answerable in a non-opinion-based way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because our guidelines say to avoid asking questions when **there is no actual problem to be solved: "I’m curious if other people feel like I do."**